# Fill out the bottom space of a div via CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fill out the bottom space of a div with `float: bottom`.

[image: Popup]

I don't think this is very uncommon but I wouldn't know how it can be done with CSS.

```css
.popup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
.popup>.top {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 60%;
  background: orange;
}
.popup>.bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class=popup>
  <div class=top>
    <input type=text />
    <input type=text />
  </div>
  <div class=bottom>I want to fill the rest of the popup!</div>
</div>
```

I know I can do this with `position: absolute` and setting the `top` with JavaScript after measuring the top div, but I prefer a CSS solution!

Can it be done?

<sup>Note: the height of both divs is dynamic.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display:flex`:

```css
.popup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex; /*Added*/
  flex-direction: column; /*Added*/
}
.popup>.top {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 60%;
  background: orange;
}
.popup>.bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1; /*Added*/
}
```

```html
<div class=popup>
  <div class=top>
    <input type=text />
    <input type=text />
  </div>
  <div class=bottom>I want to fill the rest of the popup!</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfpb4rud/)

[Documentation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: If he doesn't need support for IE9-, this is a perfect solution. Also, IE10 needs the old syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I know you have accepted an answer for `display:flex;`, however I just want to add an answer that is more cross browser friendly, using `display:table`:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfpb4rud/1/) for if the code snippet doesn't work.

```css
.popup {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: grey;
    padding: 5px;
}
.popup .top {
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
}
.popup .bottom {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}
#test1 .popup {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#test1 .popup>.bottom {
    flex: 1;
}
#test2 .popup {
    display:table;
}
#test2 .popup > .row {
    display:table-row;
}
#test2 .popup > .row > div {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<h2> Flex </h2>
<div id="test1">
    <div class=popup>
        <div class=top>
            <input type=text />
            <input type=text />
        </div>
        <div class=bottom>I want to fill the rest of the popup!</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<h2> Table </h2>
<div id="test2">
    <div class=popup>
        <div class="row">
            <div class=top>
                <input type=text />
                <input type=text />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class=bottom>I want to fill the rest of the popup!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All it requires is a little extra HTML however you do get a superior cross browser compatibility. Obviously if you're coding for a Cordova app or something then it doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: That's even better. I've just added IE classes to the HTML and decided to split everything <IE10 50/50... This is better.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.popup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.popup>.top {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 60%;
  background: orange;
}
.popup>.bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class=popup>
  <div class=top>
    <input type=text />
    <input type=text />
  </div>
  <div class=bottom>I want to fill the rest of the popup!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem very practical with `overflow: hidden`: http://jsfiddle.net/1Lz8jqh7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
.popup {
  width: 200px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
.popup>.top {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 60%;
  background: orange;
}
.popup>.bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px; /**Change height here**/
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class=popup>
  <div class=top>
    <input type=text />
    <input type=text />
  </div>
  <div class=bottom>I want to fill the rest of the popup! I want to fill the rest of the popup! I want to fill the rest of the popup! I want to fill the rest of the popup!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex.

To popup add:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction:column;
```

To bottom add:

```
flex: 1;
```

Fiddle: [Flex Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0axupff0/1/)

Reference: [Css-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/)

Hope this is what you were looking for.